# tinyint or varchar(1)?

Tags: mysql, types

I have some fields in some tables that can contain only value from `0 to 9`, and other that can contain `0 or 1`.

For your experience, is it better to store it with `TINYINT` or `VARCHAR(1)` ?

As memory usage, speed to recognize them, and so on...

Comment: tinyint unsigned probably ???

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It depends on how you are going to use the values: as strings or as numbers. If you're going to use them as numbers, `TINYINT(1)` is definitely better as mysql won't need to do unnecessary conversions. For 1-character strings you could use `CHAR(1)`.

Comment: Yeah they will be only integers. So Tinyint ;)

Comment: doesn't everything get treated as a sting outside of mysql anyways? this would only be applicable for mysql operations like `ORDER BY` et cetera, correct?

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't matter a whol lot, although I would choose `CHAR(1)` over varchar.

If you use the value as a number, ie you're going to Add or Subtract them, use TinyInt.

Otherwise, try to look ahead. Is there a chance there will ever be new values? What would be the range then?

Comment: Uhm no, they are filtered by PHP script, and can be only digit. Tinyint is 1 byte, and yeah is not so high :) I thougt about somethings like BOOLEAN for the field that store 1 or 0, but I think there isn't :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a `TINYINT(1)`, you're better off using that, as a `VARCHAR(1)` takes up twice the amount of space, per row; `TINYINT(1)` uses only 1 byte per row, whereas `VARCHAR(1)` uses 1 byte for the length, and then another byte for the actual data. This doubles the amount of data used in querying, and also any associated indexes, etc.